# Does PostgreSQL have Good Multilanguage Support on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, multilingual

I am about to use postgres for my website but want to know if it has good multilanguage support before I spend time with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "good multilanguage support" - are you asking if Postgres supports UTF-8, UTF-16 or some other character set? What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: I would like to put many different languages in the database and have fulltext on it

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using PostgeSQL on multilingual site and using it's search compatibilities. It's pretty nice in fact. Text search, however required a little bit of configuration.

Comment: In production we use FreeBSD. And Windows in development.

Answer (score 0):

The fulltext search comes with the same set of builtin dictionaries as on Unix/Linux, which is pretty good coverage. If these cover your needs, you will have the exact same functionality.

If you require custom dictionaries, they also work equally well on Windows, but you are likely going to have a harder time building the installation of them there.

Answer (score 0):

For fulltext search you can use the ispell dictionaries from http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries

The process of installation them into PostgreSQL is described here (unforunately in ukrainian, but if you are native with Russian or Linux :) you will understand this): http://grandse.org.ua/messages/show/60

http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/textsearch-dictionaries.html

Here is the common docs for TSearch2: http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/